# Why is if True slower than if 1?

Tags: python, performance, if-statement, boolean, timeit

Why is `if True` slower than `if 1` in Python? Shouldn't `if True` be faster than `if 1`?

I was trying to learn the `timeit` module. Starting with the basics, I tried these:

```
>>> def test1():
...     if True:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return 0

>>> print timeit("test1()", setup = "from __main__ import test1")
0.193144083023


>>> def test2():
...     if 1:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return 0

>>> print timeit("test2()", setup = "from __main__ import test2")
0.162086009979


>>> def test3():
...     if True:
...             return True
...     else:
...             return False

>>> print timeit("test3()", setup = "from __main__ import test3")
0.214574098587

>>> def test4():
...     if 1:
...             return True
...     else:
...             return False

>>> print timeit("test4()", setup = "from __main__ import test4")
0.160849094391
```

I am confused by these things:

1. According to the response from Mr. Sylvain Defresne in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100732/why-is-if-not-someobj-better-than-if-someobj-none-in-python), everything is implicitly converted to a `bool` first and then checked. So why is `if True` slower than `if 1`?
2. Why is `test3` slower than `test1` even though only the `return` values are different?
3. Like Question 2, but why is `test4` a little *faster* than `test2`?

NOTE: I ran `timeit` three times and took the average of the results, then posted the times here along with the code.

This question does not relate to how to do micro benchmarking(which I did in this example but I also understand that it is too basic) but why checking a 'True' variable is slower than a constant.

Comment: I think your tests are too small. And the average of three runs isn't enough :p

Comment: I understand :) even the test case is too basic to think. However, we need to start somewhere right :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long does a microbenchmark need to run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857470/how-long-does-a-microbenchmark-need-to-run)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Thanks for the link :-) However, my question is not related to generic micro bench marks. It is about why does using a keyword to check for boolean is slower than check for a constant.

Comment: True takes 4 times longer to type than the number 1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`True` and `False` are not keywords in [Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).

They must resolve at runtime. This has been changed in [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

Same test on Python 3:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('test1()',setup="from __main__ import test1", number=10000000)
2.806439919999889
>>> timeit.timeit('test2()',setup="from __main__ import test2", number=10000000)
2.801301520000038
>>> timeit.timeit('test3()',setup="from __main__ import test3", number=10000000)
2.7952816800000164
>>> timeit.timeit('test4()',setup="from __main__ import test4", number=10000000)
2.7862537199999906
```

Time error is in 1%, which is acceptable.

Comment: try `True,False=False,True`

Answer (score 21):

Bytecode disassembly makes difference obvious.

```
>>> dis.dis(test1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE            5 (to 11)
              6 POP_TOP             

  3           7 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             10 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   11 POP_TOP             

  5          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

As Kabie mentioned, `True` and `False` are globals in Python 2. Lots of stuff is going on to access them.

```
>>> dis.dis(test2)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Python compiler was able to recognize `1` as a constantly "truthy" expression and optimize redundant condition away!

```
>>> dis.dis(test3)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE            5 (to 11)
              6 POP_TOP             

  3           7 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
             10 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   11 POP_TOP             

  5          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

Pretty much the same as `test1`, with one more `LOAD_GLOBAL`.

```
>>> dis.dis(test4)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

See `test2`. But `LOAD_GLOBAL` is a bit more costly than `LOAD_CONST`.